# How to scale different sized videos proportionally in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, scaling

So I have created my vdeo player , but Im havin problems handling different sized videos. How to properly scale videos proportionally?

I get original width and height from metadata object:

```
        private function onMetaData(newMeta:Object):void
        {           
            _height = newMeta.height;
            _width = newMeta.width;
            scaleProportional();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Proportional factor

One way to do this is to calculate the proportional factor.  It is equal to the width divided by the height:

```
var proportions: Number = video.width / video.height;
```

You can apply that factor to any new width or height you set the video to:

```
function scaleProportionalByWidth ( newWidth:Number ) : void {
    video.width = newWidth;
    video.height = newWidth / proportions;
}

function scaleProportionalByHeight ( newHeight : Number ) : void {
    video.height = newHeight;
    video.width = newHeight * proportions;
}
```

### 2. Scaling factor

Another way to do it is to find out by which factor to scale the video, then set `scaleX` and `scaleY` instead of `width` and `height`:

```
function scaleProportionalByWidth ( newWidth : Number ) : void {
    scaleProportional ( newWidth, video.width );
}

function scaleProportionalByHeight ( newHeight : Number ) : void {
    scaleProportional ( newHeight, video.height );
}

function scaleProportional ( newValue:Number, oldValue : Number ) : void {
    var scale:Number = newValue / oldValue;
    video.scaleX *= scale;
    video.scaleY *= scale;
}
```

### 3. Proportional display object classes

You can also use the approach in 2. to create a proportional subclass of any `DisplayObject` by overriding the setters for `width`, `height`, `scaleX`and `scaleY` to make all scaling proportional:

```
                                           //  works for Sprite, MovieClip...
public class ProportionalDisplayObject extends DisplayObject { 
    override public function set width ( width:Number ) : void {
        scaleX = width / super.width;
    }

    override public function set height ( height:Number ) : void {
        scaleY = height / super.height;
    }

    override public function set scaleX ( scaleX : Number ) : void {
        super.scaleX = super.scaleY = scaleX;
    }

    override public function set scaleY ( scaleY : Number ) : void {
        super.scaleY = super.scaleX = scaleY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
// set video dimensions to match player;
video.width = player.width;
video.height = player.height;

// choose the larger scale property and match the other to it;
( video.scaleX < video.scaleY ) ? video.scaleY = video.scaleX : video.scaleX = video.scaleY;

// maybe center video in player ...
```